# jQuery Mobile/PhoneGap and Audio

Tags: mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm writing an HTML/CSS jQuery Mobile app to be native-compiled for iPhone, Android and Blackberry using PhoneGap Build.

The app needs to play very short spoken word audio snippets, possibly in MP3 format. What are the options for maximum cross-device compatibility?

I understand there are problems with the HTML5 audio tag, and I've had a look at jPlayer but can't get it to work on iOS 4 where the player is added to a panel element.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use the default media functions which included with phonegap itself ..

here is the link to the doc file
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html#Media